# Execute a jar with double click in linux

Tags: linux, java, shell-script, jar

What I'm trying to achieve is to run a java program on any Linux system (Ubuntu, Fedora, etc... covering as much as possible) by simply double clicking a file-like I would on Windows.
I have created a .sh file(and granted execute permissions) with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
java    -Xmx512M\
    -Djava.library.path="."\
    -DclientAppDataPath="Application Data"\
    -jar Client.jar\
    Phoenix.client.ClientMain\
    1>output.txt 2>error.txt
```

If I try to execute this file using the Ubuntu Terminal it works fine. However when I try to double click the file and choose Run or Run in Terminal, I see nothing. Apparently the shell opens and closes immediately. How do I avoid this?

**EDIT:**
I noticed error.txt contains:

> blah/blah/blah/Client Launcher.sh: 2:
>   blah/blah/blah/Client Launcher.sh: java: not found

I have extracted a jdk1.x.x.tar.gz and added java home to PATH manually using .bashrc file. Could this be the cause? How can I fix it?

Comment: Try using the full path to java.

Comment: @pjc50, Damn! It worked. That doesn't solve my problem in general (a setup program generates this file), but at least I'm sure of what's going on.

Comment: If you don't use a locally installed (i.e. not installed by the package management) version of java, your script does not know where it is located. `.bashrc` is only evaluated when you log into an interactive session.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice solution which causes Java jar files to be treated as an executable without requiring shell scripts, although it's a little fiddly to set up:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Binfmt_misc_for_Java

I believe that popular distros have packages that will sort it out for you, although I've not used it myself recently.